# override Master Page CSS div width in Child Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've set a specific width to the body div in my Master Page and I want to change that in a Child Page that belongs to the Master Page. Is this possible? I've been searching and I think what I need is javascript.

I haven't used javascript before though, but here's what I've tried:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      {
            document.getElementById("pagediv").style.width = "200px";
        }
    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to use JavaScript. You can also use CSS and have this in your content placeholder.

```
<style>
    #pagediv { width: 200px !important; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a property in your masterpage called BodyWidth

Then in your output use that for the div width

```
<div style="width:<%= BodyWidth %>">
```

Then in any child page you can override this width using something like the following in Page_Load.

```
((MyMaster)Page.MasterPage).BodyWidth = "300px";
```

Avoids using javascript then for overriding the value.

Alternatively you could use the same code but to set a style class, which would be a better way - but this depends how different your widths are on each page.

Comment: Isn't it a bit complicated to use a server variable, in fact he hardcodes the width within his script?

Comment: Which is why I suggest using a class, then the width isn't hardcoded. It is a more complicated approach I agree, but has its uses depending on the scenario.